# Jquery datatables:: Sorting data in descending order

Tags: jquery

I want to sort records in descending order.
 Here my code:

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function() {`enter code here`
    oTable = j('#example').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    });
});
</script>
```

My Sql query is:

```
$select="select * from users_tbl order by User_ID desc ";
```

Answer (score 12):

Add this attribute to your table `data-order='[[ 0, "desc" ]]'` if you want to order the results in descending order in the first column.

Example:

```
<table data-order='[[ 0, "desc" ]]' data-page-length='25'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th data-class-name="priority">Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Will give you results with ID in descending order. Just like an array, 0 means the first column, 1 means the second columns... and so on.

Comment: Perfect for me!

Answer (score 1):

Richie. Thanks for your help.

It worked for me in "Start Bootstrap - SB Admin 2 v4.1.3"

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" data-order='[[ 0, "desc" ]]' data-page-length='20'>
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30459924)